# GDAL precision for Geometry object

Tags: java, c++, precision, gdal, shapefile

recently I noticed that the [ExportToWKT](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/ogr/Geometry.html#ExportToWkt()) function of a Geometry object that has been read from a Shapefile, generates the well known text representation without any compromise on the precision of the coordinates values.

I wonder how these coordinates are represented in memory. A double precision floating type is not enough to represent some coordinates.

For example the geometry POINT (4799826.09861662145704 2773995.445373429451138) cannot be represented by two double types. But still the ExportToWKT function produces the correct result with full precision for the values.